# How to protect certain content using signed URLS in Cloudfront while letting other resources free in the internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am using the Serverless framework to do AWS development.

I have an S3 bucket with different assets inside (videos, images, etc.)

I am serving the contents of that bucket through Cloudfront.

My goal is to let some files **free in the internet (images)** and **protect others (videos)** through signed URLs without having two buckets (one for private assets and one for public ones).

At the Cloudfront level I have set TrustedSigners to self:

```
TrustedSigners:
- self
```

This is how I am thinking of achieving this goal:

1. Use custom policies like:

```
{
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Resource":"base URL or stream name",
         "Condition":{
            "DateLessThan":{
               "AWS:EpochTime":ending date and time in Unix time format and UTC
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I could use wildcards maybe for the image resources. The problem is I am not sure this is possible and I have no idea where to put this policy in the serverless.yml file.

Is this policy set at the sdk level?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudfront-distribution.html
I do not see anywhere where I can declare the custom policy.

2. Have two Cloudfront distributions and somehow set filter the content of the files they are serving.  One cloudfront would serve the images from the S3 bucket while the other the videos. I'm not sure this is possible also.

How would you guys do it?
Is there a chance?

Thank you!

Comment: You can work this out with Cache behavious, Trusted signers are used in Cache behaviours, you can have different cache behaviors based on path such as /images , /video or even *.jpg etc

Comment: I am trying this, ty @JamesDean ! Any idea if PathPattern supports regex? PathPattern: .+HLS.+ver\d+.m3u8

Comment: Also, please write an answer so I can approve it because this seems the solution to go with

Comment: Path pattern doesn't support regex yet, it supports only wildcards currently:           * matches 0 or more characters.
? matches exactly 1 character. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern

Answer (score 0):

You can work this out with Cache behaviours, Trusted signers are used in Cache behaviours, you can have different cache behaviours based on path such as /images , /video or even *.jpg etc

```
Path pattern doesn't support regex yet, it supports wildcards currently: 
* matches 0 or more characters. 
? matches exactly 1 character.
```

[CloudFront cache behaviour](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern)